# how to use `heapq.merge`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge, heapq

Here's the snippet I've been trying:

```
>>> L1 = [i for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0]
>>> L2 = [j for j in range(10) if j % 2]

>>> import heapq
>>> [k for k in heapq.merge(L1, L2)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> [k for k in heapq.merge(L1, L2, reverse=True)]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

I was expecting `[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]` because of `reverse=True`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the doc: "reverse is a boolean value. If set to True, then the input elements are merged as if each comparison were reversed. To achieve behavior similar to sorted(itertools.chain(*iterables), reverse=True), all iterables must be sorted from largest to smallest." So at each step, merge yields the largest ot the two numbers available at the start of each list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Thierry Lathuille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/550094/thierry-lathuille)'s comment. I figured it out. Its a very round about way though.

```
>>> L1 = [i for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0]
>>> L2 = [j for j in range(10) if j % 2]
>>> M = [k for k in heapq.merge(sorted(L1, reverse=True), sorted(L2, reverse=True), reverse=True)]
>>> M
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

For merging 2 lists sorted in ascending order but the output should be in descending order, this seems to be much simpler:

```
>>> sorted(L1 + L2, reverse=True)
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```